# Android Data Binding: Pass variable to NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

When a user signs into my app and I receive their profile info (name, avatar, etc) in `MainActivity`, I'd like to populate some fields in my Navigation View Header with the user params via Data Binding. I've tried the method proposed in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes), but maybe it is limited to `<include />` only?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.example.app.models.User" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        // layout params... >

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            bind:user="@{user}" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.example.app.models.User" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    // layout params... >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@{user.name}"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setUser(User.getInstance());
// other stuff...
}
```

I get 2 errors:

1. error: cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBinding
2. Cannot find the setter for attribute 'bind:user' with parameter type com.example.app.models.User on android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.

If I remove the `bind:user` line it builds, but it doesn't work of course. Any way to get this sort of thing to work?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/layout_nav_view_header">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="user"
                type="com.myapp.model.UserSettings"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:text="@{user.name}"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle"
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And then in the activity's onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val viewHeader = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
    val navViewHeaderBinding : NavHeaderMainBinding = NavHeaderMainBinding.bind(viewHeader)
    navViewHeaderBinding.user = UserSettings(null, null, "John Doe", "Android Developer", null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @AndroidDev did work for me basically and seems to be the cleanest one for me.
But I tried to set a viewModel to a databinding-variable and access its LiveData-instances and methods in the nav-header view:

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.MainActivityViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_logout_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.handleLoginLogoutButton()}"
        android:text='@{viewModel.user == null ? "Login" : "Logoff"}'
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/textstyle_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text='Abmelden' />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.user.email}"
        android:textAppearance="@style/textstyle_body1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.userCredentialsVisibility}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_logout_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="kuku@gmail.com"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
  ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This was not working at first, since the viewModel-LiveData-changes did not propagate to the generated NavHeaderMainBinding instance.

I had quite a headache, I did implement the Observable-interface in my ViewModel as explained in the official databinding-docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#observable-viewmodel

But that did not fix this particular issue.
Then I remembered that the databinding-docs mentioned to set the LifeCycleOwner on the generated Binding-class. I did that for the NavHeaderMainBinding and now it is working:

MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ...
    // this has to be in onPostCreate to avoid a IllegalStateException
    // while using FragmentContainerView as NavHost in MainActivity (activity_main.xml)
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    // we have to bind the viewModel manually to the header-view
    // since NavigationView does not support databinding by itself
    val headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
    val headerViewBinding = NavHeaderMainBinding.bind(headerView)
    headerViewBinding.viewModel = mainActivityViewModel
    // this new line is important to get notifications about livedata-changes!!!
    headerViewBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
    // ...
}
```

Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the navigation view programmatically to enable binding.

```
NavHeaderHomeBinding _bind = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.nav_header_main, binding
            .navView, false);
    binding.navView.addHeaderView(_bind);
```

Your xml : Remove headerLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        bind:user="@{user}" />
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

[ksinghit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7265971/ksinghit)'s answer did not work for me. For some reason Gradle is not able to build when I try to bind the user variable via XML. 
But based on his answer I was able to remove the `bind:user` line and set the variable programmatically:

```
_bind.user = user
```

Just an observation to anyone else using Kotlin: when adding the Header View you must pass the view root and not the NavHeaderHomeBinding itself:

```
binding.navView?.addHeaderView(_bind.root)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer"
  android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">

  <include layout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
    app:user= "@{user}"/>
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```